# Derive the partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

"Consider the function
$$ F(u) = \int_{\Omega}[ \frac{1}{2} \nabla u(x) |^2 + g(x) u(x)] dx $$
and the set 
$$K = \{  v \in H^1 (\Omega): v = 0\   \text{on} \  \partial \Omega\  in\  the \ sense\  of\  traces \}$$

Let $ u \in H^1(\Omega)$ be the solution of the minimization problem " Minimize f(v) among all functions v belonging to set K". Assuming that such a solution exits, derive the partial differential equation that is solved by u. In what sense does u solve this partial differential equation? "

Is this problem still the sames as energy minimization problem? ( the space $H^1(\Omega)$ instead of $C^1 (\Omega)$) . Thanks you very much.

Comment: Essentially, the problem is asking you to write down the Euler-Lagrange equation of the functional $F(u)$. Yes, they are equivalent formulation: minimising $F(u)$ is equivalent to solving a certain PDEs in a weak sense. You might find information about Dirichlet energy helpful (: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_energy

Comment: So the PDE will be $\nabla u= -f$ and $ u = 0 $ on $\partial \Omega$, right?

Comment: No, it should be $\Delta u = f$ in $\Omega$.